Copying data from two columns and pasting into the same columns based on Band # in R
I have the following dataframe.
df <- data.frame(
Capture_Date = as.Date(c("2025-01-01", "2025-07-01", "2026-01-01", "2025-01-01", "2025-01-01",
                       "2025-07-01", "2025-01-01", "2025-07-01", "2025-01-01", "2025-07-01")),
Treatment = rep("ALL", 10),
Course = rep("Dixie", 10),
Trap = c("T30", "T30", "RT30", "T30", "T28", "T28", "T28", "T28", "T28", "T28"),
Band = c("803", "803", "803", "804", "807", "807", "808", "808", "809", "809"),
Sex = c("F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M"),
Age = rep("J", 10),
Weight = c("152", "152", "152", "156", "152", "152", "139", "139", "156", "156"),
Frequency = c(151.571, 151.571, 151.571, 151.602, 151.16, 151.16, 151.149, 151.149, 151.24,     151.24),
Primary = rep("", 10),
Cause = c("", "", "censor", "LA", "", "LA", "", "UNK", "", "LA"),
Fate_Date = as.Date(c(NA, NA, "2026-07-01", "2025-06-01", NA, "2025-08-01", NA, "2025-09-01",   NA, "2025-08-27"))
)

There are sometimes multiple captures for a singular animal (Band is unique to each animal) but there is only one entry for Cause and Fate_Date. I am trying to copy and paste the Cause and Fate_Date Columns to fill in the missing data for each row and then subset to using just the oldest Capture date so it only shows the first capture date and the day the animal was fated and the cause. I am having a hard time copying the Cause and Fate_Date's based on Band, it seems simple to do but I am running into trouble.
enter image description here
I have tried pulling out the oldest entry and then merging that with the original dataframe, but that did not work as it just created new columns without doing anything else. I just need to copy and past the Cause and Fate_Date columns based on the Band column.

Sounds like you want to fill in missing values by group. With library(tidyverse) you can do df |> group_by(Band) |> fill(Cause, Fate_Date, .direction = "downup") |> ungroup(). You may need to change your blanks "" to NA first.

Suggested duplicate: Replace NA values with most recent non-NA value by group.

Base: na.locf = \(x) { i = !is.na(x); c(NA, x[i])[cumsum(i) + 1L]}; ave(df$Cause, df$Band, FUN = \(x) { x[x == ""] = NA; na.locf(rev(x)) }), for other cases rev() must be removed and a proper ordering implemented.

It has already been answered in the comment section. The entire process involves converting "" values to NA, then applying the fill from the tidyr package to the grouped dataframe.
library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(
        Capture_Date = as.Date(c("2025-01-01", "2025-07-01", "2026-01-01", "2025-01-01", "2025-01-01",
                                 "2025-07-01", "2025-01-01", "2025-07-01", "2025-01-01", "2025-07-01")),
        Treatment = rep("ALL", 10),
        Course = rep("Dixie", 10),
        Trap = c("T30", "T30", "RT30", "T30", "T28", "T28", "T28", "T28", "T28", "T28"),
        Band = c("803", "803", "803", "804", "807", "807", "808", "808", "809", "809"),
        Sex = c("F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M"),
        Age = rep("J", 10),
        Weight = c("152", "152", "152", "156", "152", "152", "139", "139", "156", "156"),
        Frequency = c(151.571, 151.571, 151.571, 151.602, 151.16, 151.16, 151.149, 151.149, 151.24,     151.24),
        Primary = rep("", 10),
        Cause = c("", "", "censor", "LA", "", "LA", "", "UNK", "", "LA"),
        Fate_Date = as.Date(c(NA, NA, "2026-07-01", "2025-06-01", NA, "2025-08-01", NA, "2025-09-01",   NA, "2025-08-27"))
) 


filled_df <- df |> mutate(Cause = ifelse(Cause == "", NA, Cause)) |> 
        group_by(Band) |> 
        fill(Cause, Fate_Date, .direction = "downup") |> 
        ungroup()

filled_df |> select(Band, Cause, Fate_Date)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Band  Cause  Fate_Date 
#>    <chr> <chr>  <date>    
#>  1 803   censor 2026-07-01
#>  2 803   censor 2026-07-01
#>  3 803   censor 2026-07-01
#>  4 804   LA     2025-06-01
#>  5 807   LA     2025-08-01
#>  6 807   LA     2025-08-01
#>  7 808   UNK    2025-09-01
#>  8 808   UNK    2025-09-01
#>  9 809   LA     2025-08-27
#> 10 809   LA     2025-08-27

Created on 2024-05-13 with reprex v2.1.0
